# Получить объект из xml и преобразовать в число

Tags: php, xml

коллеги. Помогите решить задачу. Пишу виджет информера валют, получаю информацию о актуальном курсе валют, вытягивая её со специального файла от нац банка в формате xml, вытягиваю нужные значения, но "вытягиваются" они как объекты, следовательно я не могу проводить с ними ни какие операции. Не могу округлить, высчитать разницу курса между вчера и сегодня и т.д.

Подскажите, как преобразовать объект в числовое значение в данном коде.
В данном случае я имею ввиду  $currency->rate.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange");

foreach ($xml->currency as $currency) {
    if ($currency-> r030 == 978) {
        echo $currency->txt.' '.  $currency->rate.'</br >';
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Так вот, всё просто, чтобы принять от xml строковое значение нужно просто добавить (string) перед получением обьекта, например

```
round((string)$currency->rate, 2)
```